# ZFS on Linux - one of four drives removed

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I have a small server with 4 drive bays in the front, all have an identical 3TB drive. Now ZFS reports one drive is removed. The machine sees the drive but I can’t get the drive to become not removed. I reckon the issue is my lack of knowledge, but a poke in the right direction is greatly appreciated!
Thanks guys!

Comment: Please provide the output of `zpool status`, `fdisk -l` and of running `smartctl -a /dev/whatever` against the “removed” disk.

Comment: Ok, I’ve just got home and run ‘zpool status’ and it says all disks are online! Is there anything I should worry about here, or is it fine you think? ‘Fdisk -l’ lists my 5 disks (my pool is on the 4 plus a disk for my os) ... I can get the smart info if you like, if you could help?

Comment: That’s great to hear! If you feel the question is no longer needed, you can delete it. // I recommend you scrub the pool and check for what could’ve caused the disk to disconnect: bad/loose cables, bad enclose, bad disk, …

Comment: Well when it was removed, the drive was still attached and visible to the machine. But when I tried to connect the drive to the pool it just wouldn’t?? It just kept saying removed in ‘zpool status’ so I’m still none the wiser as to what went on?! Thanks for your help anyway!!! You’re a star